# Dot: How to decorate graph nodes with black outline while filled with another color?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I need help with formatting a dot graph. To simplify my question, I have a dot code here which I run through a dot tool:

```
digraph G
{
   TestNode [label="Test Node", shape="egg" style="filled" color="yellow"]
}
```

results in this:

[image]

I want to have a black outline to this node. How can I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `fillcolor` together with `color` does achieve what you're after:

```
TestNode [label="Test Node", shape="egg", style="filled", color="black", fillcolor="yellow"]
```

[image: Graphviz node with outline]

From the [documentation:](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:fillcolor)

> Color used to fill the background of a node or cluster assuming
>   style=filled. If fillcolor is not defined, color is used.