# Graphviz: How to change border color

Tags: graph, colors, border, graphviz

Given a node like so, on a white background

```
"test" [
    style="filled,dashed"
    shape=box
    color=lightgray
    label="Hello World"
];
```

How do I make the dashed border black?

Comment: also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168549/dot-how-to-decorate-graph-nodes-with-black-outline-while-filled-with-another-co

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I found a solution that works in my case.

```
"test" [
    style="filled,dashed"
    shape=box
    color=black
    fillcolor=lightgray
    label="Hello World"
];
```

It was misleading because if `fillcolor` is not specified, it appears it will default to `color`.

Comment: Correct. As the documentation says, [if fillcolor is not defined, color is used](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs#dfillcolor).

Comment: @ryandesign's link is dead.  [current](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:fillcolor)

Comment: Importantly, the order of the arguments matters here. Specifying `color` after `fillcolor` seems to overwrite the filling color (or at least that's the behavior when used with VisJS)

Answer (score 6):

So You can actually get this with one less line:

```
"test" [
    style="filled,dashed"
    shape=box
    fillcolor=lightgray
    label="Hello World"
];
```

In my testing at least including a `fillcolor` with no `color` defaults to black border.